# Too few columns for technology sites in stackexchange.com footer

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stackexchange.com, footer

On https://stackexchange.com, if you click 'Technology' in the footer, you get a list of (the oldest?) sites in that category. They are neatly divided into several columns, except for the last one, Windows Phone, which gets its own row:

[image]

There's enough room for it on the right, as is also the case e.g. here on Meta Stack Exchange:

[image]

<sub>Given that Windows Phone OS is end of life, I wouldn't mind it being removed entirely (from the footer, not from the network), but I guess that would leave the 'more (29)' link in the same position.</sub>

Comment: I wouldn't remove Windows Phone yet, but moving it to the right is definitely a good idea.

Comment: Windows phone is just trying to socially distance ;)

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour of those links in the footer has been changed; instead of expanding to a list of sites, it now links to [a filtered version of the site list on stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology). This is also true for the footer on all sites. All of this happened in 2021 between [November 18th](http://web.archive.org/web/20211118001702/https://meta.stackexchange.com/) and [November 19th](http://web.archive.org/web/20211119201841/https://meta.stackexchange.com/).